# How to upgrade Flurry from 2.8.4 to 3.0.0 in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, flurry

We have been using Flurry 2.8.4 and wish to upgrade to 3.0.0

Anyone know of a simple process to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove LibFlurry.a from binary libraries linked list, include the new .a version. Then recompile, you will get a few errors since a couple of method names have changed, correct those and you're done. 
It's standard for replacing any static library.